# Given $\alpha$ , $\beta$ respectively the fifth and the fourth non-real roots of unity then the value of

Tags: complex-numbers

Given $\alpha$ , $\beta$ respectively the fifth and the fourth non-real roots of unity then the value of $\left(1+\alpha \right)\left(1+\beta \right)\left(1+\alpha ^2\right)\left(1+\beta ^2\right)\left(1+\alpha ^3\right)\left(1+\beta ^3\right)\left(1+\alpha ^4\right)$ will be ?

After seeing this question on first sight i though it would be an easy one as $x^4 -1 = 0$ and i will then apply $(x-1)(x-\alpha)...(x-\alpha ^{n-1}))$ but there is + sign between expression so i thought multiplying and dividing $(1-\alpha)$ and $(1-\beta)$ would help but the $(1+\alpha^{3})$ term is making trouble for me .

Options are (A) $0$ (B) $1$ (C) $(1+\alpha+\alpha^{2})(1-\beta^{2})$ (D) $(1+\alpha)(1+\beta+\beta^{2})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the $\beta$ terms alone, multiplying the first two brackets gives $$(1+\beta)(1+\beta^2)=1+\beta+\beta^2+\beta^3=0$$ so the answer is A

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You have $\beta = \pm i$

Comment: I got my term $\frac{\left(1-\alpha \:^8\right)\left(1-\beta \:^4\right)\left(1+\beta ^3\right)}{\left(1-\alpha \:\right)\left(1-\beta \right)}$ and if i look at the term involving $\alpha$ it is an G.P. and if i remember correctly then its answers comes 0 if $p$ is not integral multiple of $n$ where $n$ are number of terms and $p$ is last term power . So should the answer be $0$ ?

Comment: Even simpler, since $\beta = \pm i, \beta^2=-1, (1+\beta^2)=0$ and the product is $0$